# `unsafeCoerce` implementation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have heard that various type system hacks in Haskell (`unsafePerformIO`, Template Haskell, arbitrary-rank polymorphism,...) can be used to coerce different types, but I haven't seen the explicit implementations. How is it done, at least in GHC?

Comment: The three things you mention are very different: `unsafePerformIO` is, well, unsafe; Template Haskell is a way of generating code at compile time; and rank-n polymorphism is a more powerful but still sound type system.  That's why, [as chi explained well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22115147/237428), only the first is dangerous.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## On unsafePerformIO

You can use `unsafePerformIO` to create top-level `IORef`s, i.e. mutable global variables. If you add polymorphism to this, you lose type safety as follows:

```
myVar :: IORef a -- polymorphic ref!
myVar = unsafePerformIO $ newIORef undefined

coerce :: a -> b
coerce x = unsafePerformIO $ do
    writeIORef myVar x  -- write value of type a
    readIORef myVar     -- read value of type b
```

Basically, a (non bottom) value of type `forall a. IORef a` should not exist, ever. Its type states that you can use it as a mutable variable of the type you want, so you can write to it pretending it has one type, and then read from it pretending it has another type.

Note that monomorphic top-level `IORef`s do not lead to type unsafety, since you can only write and read those at the same type.

## On others

Higher ranks are type safe, AFAIK.

I also do not know about Template Haskell.

Another source of type unsafety is user-written `Typeable` instances, since those allow you to claim your own new datatype is actually an `Int` and successfully use `cast` to coerce values.

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to introduce type unsoundness using Template Haskell without using some other mechanism that itself introduces type unsoundness.  While a template haskell `Exp` has an unknown type (and may be polymorphic!), the splices are always type checked at the point they are expanded.

Comment: The `IORef`s don't need to be top-level, just polymorphic.  This issue is also what motivates the value restriction in MLs.